# My 9 hours project seems gone

Tags: mesh, rigging

Everytime I finish a scene in my project I save it , this time I save it and there was a blend1 file.

Tried to open it in blender by open file , but now every time I open my file blender crashes.

I cant even open my file it just keeps crashing or it doesn't even launch p

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what exactly went wrong and with the information you provided I never will. Blend1 file is a backup file that you should be able to open in blender and is saved automatically along the .blend file.

Seeing your tmp folder I get it you tried older autosaves and other backup files whether you can access them and restore the work from them?

If you did, nevermind, you might still be able to save whatever was in the file. Just create a new blend file and go FILE -> APPEND and find the file you want to restore.From here you can access all the data stored in the .blend file (providing the data itself is not corrupted), append it to a new .blend file and resave it.

[image]